# C# RestSharp JSON Syntax

Tags: c#, json, authentication, restsharp

I seem to have a syntax problem with my JSON body.
The code is intended to retrieve the balance from LetterXpress using an API, but instead of being able to authenticate, I receive the response:

> ("{"message":"Unauthorized."}")

The request works fine using Postman.

Here is my C# code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.letterxpress.de/v2/balance");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

string jsonString = "{" +
    "\"auth\": {" +
        "\"username\" : \"LXPApi1\"," +
        "\"apikey\" : \"442807b35e250ec767221fe3ba\"," +
        "\"mode\" : \"live\"" +
    "}" + "}";
request.AddJsonBody(jsonString);
IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
string meinString = response.Content;
textBox4.Text = meinString;
```

With this code, I have tried so far. My suspicion is that the syntax in the `jsonString` is incorrect. However, I cannot find the error.

Comment: Have you tried to send the request via Postman to verify whether your request body is correct? While recommend serializing the value for JSON with a library such as *System.Text.Json* or *Newtonsoft.Json*, instead of manually serializing with your own, highly chance you might serialize the JSON incorrectly.

Comment: Json should be structural correct or you should have gotten a different Response. Are you sure your credentials are correct? Or if that needed for the API you use is your account activated? The message Unauthorized is so specific that it does not sound like you did something formally wrong in the request body but rather your credentials are simply not valid.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt responses.
The credentials are correct as I am able to retrieve the balance value using the Postman program.
I will try it with the System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json library and provide feedback.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you even using the right http method? You're adding a body to a GET request.

Comment: please, attach a successful postman request...

Answer (score 1):

*"My suspicion is that the syntax in the jsonString is incorrect."* Close, it's one of the problems with your code.

#### JSON Encoded String!

`AddJsonBody` expects an object that will be serialized automatically - [see the documentation](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#request-body). What you're doing is effectively JSON encoding a string so the request will never be able to deserialize it to your expectations.

What you should be doing instead is pass an object that has all the expected properties. You can use an anonymous object, or a concrete class, for the request body:

```cs
var body = new {
    auth = new {
        username = "LXPApi1",
        apikey = "442807b35e250ec767221fe3ba",
        mode = "live"
    }
};
request.AddJsonBody(body);
```

#### GET Request With Body

You're sending a GET request and attempting to include a body with the request which is not valid for GET requests. The chances are that you should be sending a POST request instead.

Unfortunately the [API Documentation (in German)](https://www.letterxpress.de/briefe-uebertragen/api) shows a GET request which most, if not all, HTTP clients will not support and are likely to not include the body of the request even though you have set it.

#### Side Notes

- I would advise that you never create JSON manually and always leverage existing JSON serialization tools to convert objects to JSON.
- Never expose any credentials in a question.

Answer (score 0):

you are building request incorrectly
here is a good call, but not authorized.

```cs
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var options = new RestClientOptions("https://api.letterxpress.de")
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
        //ThrowOnAnyError = true,
        //MaxTimeout = 1000,
    };
    using (RestClient client = new RestClient(options))
    {
        string jsonString = "{" +
        "\"auth\": {" +
            "\"username\" : \"LXPApi1\"," +
            "\"apikey\" : \"442807b35e250ec767221fe3ba\"," +
            "\"mode\" : \"live\"" +
        "}" + "}";

        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString).Dump();
        var request = new RestRequest("/v2/balance", Method.Get)
            .AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .AddBody(jsonString);
        var response = client.ExecuteAsync(request).Result;
        Console.Write(response.Content);
        
    }
```

still not authorized, as you mentioned - code runs wwith postman request please add a screenshot of postman request
[image]